# Is there a good English to Russian dictionary about swear words?

Tags: resources, мат, словарь

I'm looking for a dictionary, English to Russian, that lists swear words and goes into depth about them. By "good" in the title, I meant that it should translate also less known/common swear words appropriately into Russian, also, slang words should be included.

It can be both a dictionary with these swear words included, or a dictionary about it only.

Other than the link, please *include* why you're proposing that solution and why you think it's better than others.

Comment: I know of many russian dictionaries of swear words, jail dialects etc. But never saw a good Russian to English dictionary. I would love to read that. Though it might be hard to come up with one because it is all about concepts and is not really directly translatable.

Comment: @VladLazarenko What do you think about [this page](http://www.russki-mat.net/e/Russian.php)

Comment: @Em1: It is actually great! I think it would a pretty good answer!

Comment: Sadly I have to say there's no such thing as a "good EN-RU swear language dictionary" as Russian is more than just a collection of profanities - it has it's own culture and it's own linguistic apparatus. If you want to properly swear in Russian you have to learn the Russian swearing language as you would learn any other language you wish to speak, including grammar, word forming, cultural references, and countless exceptions to the rules

Comment: May be wiktionary.org meets your criteria?

Answer (score 8):

I found a dictionary called [Пиздец!](http://www.russki-mat.net/e/Russian.php), a Russian-English slang dictionary.

In the introducing it says:

> The following 1,700 words and expressions are rude, naughty and generally not something you would say in front of your mother.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a method. You translate an English swear word [here](http://matno.ru/index/perevodchik_maternyh_slov_onlajn/0-4/) and next search for it in the [defining dictionary](http://mat.al.ru/). I use it, because I have never seen all-in-one solutions.

Comment: Nice try, but that dictionary is very primitive. The first thing I've tried was a word "douche" and it totally failed, same for "douchebag".

Answer (score 0):

*А. Ю. Кудрявцев, Г. Д. Куропаткин*
Англо-русский словарь-справочник табуизированной лексики и эвфемизмов / ABC of Dirty English.
Москва, «КОМПТ», 1993
It includes lists of words related to some general 'topic', e. g. ‘DAMN(ED)’.

There is also a newer edition with a title which differs a little.